# Disable pause button in shockwave player

Tags: html, css, flash

the following is my embedded audio in a webpage. I would like to disable the pause so that the users must listen to the whole audio.

Below is my code

```
<embed class="qmedia" flashvars="file=https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_eFBezdONieTDP7L&amp;width=322&amp;height=262&amp;
type=mp3&amp;autostart=true" height="262" 
pluginspage="http://adobe.com/flashplayer/" 
src="../WRQualtricsShared/Flash/flvplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="322" wmode="transparent">
```

I have tried all options like showControls in the HTML, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Have you done any research, such as Google "flash player disable pause"?  What makes you think this is possible?  How would you feel, and what would you do if you visited a web page and found you couldn't pause the sound?  Are you deliberately trying to alienate your users?  Maybe if you explained your use case and what research you've done this wouldn't seem quite so inappropriate.

Comment: Yes I agree that disabling the pause button is an unusual request. I develop surveys related to psychology where my boss seems to be very specific about not letting the users pause the audio when it starts playing.

Comment: You'll probably have a better chance of getting a useful answer on a Flash/Shockwave forum at Adobe.

Comment: I'm not really into audio, but the `<audio>` element seems to have a `controls` attribute that allows you to hide or show all controls. Including, presumably, the pause button and the slider to go back and forth. See [W3C page](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/audio.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set both the height and the width of the player to 0